Why does CSS of input element change with max attribute?
I have two input elements, both of which are of type number, and both of which have a min value of 0.
However, the second element also has a max attribute set to 100, and it appears this element has less width than the first one.


<input type="number" min="0" />
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" />



Does anyone know why the second element's CSS changes when adding that max attribute?
Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8e3bys07/

the browser decided that's enough width to hold the max value which is 100

Indeed, with no max the input has to be wide enough to accomodate a gigantic number just in case. Otherwise it would have to expand to adjust for the width as each number is input.
